# org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypeException: Unsupported dataType: IntegerType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and Scala i am stuck on this exception, I am trying to add some extra fields, i.e. StructField to an existing StructType retrieved from Data Frame for a column using Spark SQL and gettting below exception.

code snippet:

```
val dfStruct:StructType=parquetDf.select("columnname").schema
dfStruct.add("newField","IntegerType",true)
```

Exception in thread "main"

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypeException: Unsupported dataType: IntegerType. If you have a struct and a field name of it has any special characters, please use backticks (`) to quote that field name, e.g. `x+y`. Please note that backtick itself is not supported in a field name.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypeParser$class.toDataType(DataTypeParser.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypeParser$$anon$1.toDataType(DataTypeParser.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypeParser$.parse(DataTypeParser.scala:111)
```

I can see there some open issues running on jira related to this exception but not able to understand much. I am using Spark 1.5.1 version

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-issues/201508.mbox/%3CJIRA.12852533.1438855066000.143133.1440397426473@Atlassian.JIRA%3E

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-issues/201508.mbox/%3CJIRA.12852533.1438855066000.143133.1440397426473@Atlassian.JIRA%3E

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `StructType.add` with a following signature:

```
add(name: String, dataType: String, nullable: Boolean)
```

`dataType` string should correspond to either `.simpleString` or `.typeName`. For `IntegerType` it is either `int`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

IntegerType.simpleString
// String = int
```

or `integer`:

```
IntegerType.typeName
// String = integer
```

so what you need is something like this:

```
val schema = StructType(Nil)

schema.add("foo", "int", true)
// org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = 
//   StructType(StructField(foo,IntegerType,true))
```

or

```
schema.add("foo", "integer", true)
// org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = 
//   StructType(StructField(foo,IntegerType,true))
```

If you want to pass `IntegerType` it has to be `DataType` not `String`:

```
schema.add("foo", IntegerType, true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response zero323, I am now able to append StructFiled to existing StructType. The cause was my IDE has not imported "import  org.apache.spark.sql.types._" hence was not able to compile this code 
      StructType(
    StructField("column1", DoubleType, false) ::
    StructField("column2", DoubleType, false) ::
    StructField("column3", StringType, false) ::Nil) 

 hence i was tyring with api dfStruct.add("newField","IntegerType",true)
 
after writing the import statement manually i am able to fix this problem.